# O objeto não dá suporte para a propriedade ou método no util.js da api do Google

Tags: delphi, google-maps-api-3

Tenho uma aplicação em Delphi XE7 que carrega um mapa do google para gerar rota no TWebBrowser, porém ao gerar a rota a mesma é mostrada só que gera erro quando vai colocar o caminho descrito no elemento. Tentei utilizar api da versão 18 até a 23, mas não surtiu efeito.

Até via browser se usar IE8 ocorre o problema.

Notei que foram adicionados atributos jstcache e jsaction nas tags das directions

Chamo o método mapa.directions_display.setDirections(result);

[image: Erro]

Tentei adicionar a metatag pro IE=9, mas daí meu mapa não carrega.

--Alterei via registro através do link https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version e funcionou somente para o IE11. Alguma sugestão para meus clientes que possuem windows XP, que não seja a migração de sistema operacional?

Começou do nada hoje pela manhã.

Comment: Tente colocar na propriedade do TWebBrowser Silent=True

Answer (score 1):

O google não oferece mais suporte para o IE 8, para mim aconteceu exatamente a mesma coisa, mas infelizmente não há o que fazer no Windows XP, somente no Windows 7 ou superior, onde existe ou pode ser instalado, o IE 11 e fazer este procedimento de adicionar uma chave no registro.